# Import data from Excel to a DataTable Dynamically vb.net

Tags: sql-server, excel, vb.net

I have a form that main idea is that will allow the user to import data from excel to the Database dynamically, he will specify the columns where he required the information as display in the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/865mz.png)

but when I transfer the data to a data table I have use difference cycles to import that data to a data table but it always end up looking like the image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFECl.png)

this is my code

Dim dtTtable, tempdtTable, tmpClmDtTable As New DataTable
            dtTtable = Ejecutar_Query("Select * From " & ComboBoxEdit1.EditValue, False)

```
        For clmn = 0 To ImportacionDtTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim sRange As String = ImportacionDtTable(clmn).Item(1)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sRange) = False Then
                Dim nrw As DataRow = dtTtable.NewRow
                tmpClmDtTable = New DataTable
                tmpClmDtTable = GetDataExcel(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, SpreadsheetControl1.ActiveWorksheet.Name, sRange)
                tempdtTable.Merge(tmpClmDtTable)

                'tempdtTable = tmpClmDtTable.Copy
            End If

        Next
        'dtTtable.AcceptChanges()

        Dim tablas As New Form_Tabla
        With tablas
            .PdtTable = tempdtTable
            .ShowDialog()
            .Close()
        End With
```

I have use marge right now just to show how it end up the columns at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, I will let the code for anyone how may have a similar problem

```
       Dim dtTtable, TempT1, TempT2 As New DataTable
        dtTtable = Ejecutar_Query("Select * From " & ComboBoxEdit1.EditValue, False)

 'Ejecurtar_Query is a pu`blic function that returns a datarow or data table i get the structure of the table I want.`

        Dim nfil As Integer = 0
        Dim dRange As String = Nothing
        For clmn = 0 To ImportacionDtTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim sRange As String = ImportacionDtTable(clmn).Item(1),
                clmName As String = ImportacionDtTable(clmn).Item(0)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sRange) = False Then
                TempT1 = New DataTable
                TempT1 = GetDataExcel(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, SpreadsheetControl1.ActiveWorksheet.Name, sRange)
                Dim dtCl As New DataColumn
'I create a new datacolumn then I add it in the my second data table 

                dtCl = TempT1.Columns(0)
                TempT2.Columns.Add(clmName, dtCl.DataType)

                If TempT2.Rows.Count < TempT1.Rows.Count Then
                    For n = 0 To TempT1.Rows.Count - TempT2.Rows.Count
                        TempT2.Rows.Add()
                    Next
                End If
                Dim nCl As Integer = TempT2.Columns.Count

                For fila = 0 To TempT1.Rows.Count - 1
                    TempT2(fila).Item(nCl - 1) = TempT1(fila).Item(0)
                Next

            End If
        Next


  'then after I create the table, my data table where I need the data on, will add the rows then I will navigate in my temporary datatable to insert the data to later display it in a grid

        For x = 0 To TempT2.Rows.Count - 1
            dtTtable.Rows.Add()
        Next
        Dim nitm As Integer = 0
        For clmn = 0 To ImportacionDtTable.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim sRange As String = ImportacionDtTable(clmn).Item(1)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sRange) = False Then
                For nFila = 0 To TempT2.Rows.Count - 1
                    dtTtable(nFila).Item(clmn) = TempT2(nFila).Item(nitm)
                Next
                nitm += 1
            End If
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Book1.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```